# Notepad++ COBOL Comment Highlighting with Line Numbers

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

##### How can I get COBOL comments to use proper syntax highlighting in Notepad++ when line numbers are filled in columns 1-6?

I am a developer who is using Notepad++ to code in COBOL.  I use the built-in COBOL syntax highlighting, which works under most conditions, but has a particular issue.

COBOL comments are indicated by an asterisk as the 7th character in a line - ordinarily, this works correctly.  However, **if the 6th character** in the line immediately preceding the asterisk **is also filled in,** the line will incorrectly **fail to register as a comment.**

Example:

```
      * THIS SHOWS AS A COMMENT
SH0819* THIS DOES NOT SHOW AS A COMMENT
     9* NEITHER DOES THIS
```

In COBOL, lines 1-6 are used for "line numbers", or alternatively, initials and dates as a form of primitive manual version control.  It is common to have these characters filled in, and they should not interfere with the syntax in any way.

##### Is there a way to prevent the 6th character from impacting the syntax highlighting of the 7th character?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but maybe this will help someone. I recently started programming in Unisys COBOL and noticed the issue you are referring to. To fix it, you will need to rebuild NPP. It is open source on Git.

`LexCOBOL.cxx` is the program that needs to be updated.  Around line 210 is an if statement that starts `if (isCOBOLwordstart(ch) || ....`  You need to add an additional condition that checks if the column number is 7 or greater. The new if statement starts like this:

```
if (column > 6 && (isCOBOLwordstart(ch) || ....)
```

[image: LexCOBOL.cxx Change to fix COBOL comment issue.]

Answer (score 2):

First case: begin coding in col 1 and will be treated like col 7
(Notepad++ works good)
[image: Case #1]

Second case: begin coding in col 8, and will be treated like standard
editor COBOL.
[image: Case #2]

When col 6 is coding, then Notepad++ assumes line as case 1. (Remarks don't work in this case).

I use SPFLite. This editor works as ISPF on Mainframe.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working almost exclusively with old, pre-existing code as opposed to writing new code, so I don't think this is a practical solution for me.